# change a td content using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I built a table dynamically using jquery. Below my code:

```
<div class="scroll-pane">
   <table class="table support-table">
    <thead>
        <th id="support-field-1"></th>
        <th id="support-field-3"></th>
        <th id="support-field-4"></th>
        <th id="support-field-5"></th>
        <th id="support-field-6"></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>

<script>
var container = $('.support-table tbody');
var ticket;
var j;
for(var i = 0; i < support.length; i++) {
    var id=support[i].identification!=null ? support[i].identification : '';
    var sdateTime = support[i].sdateTime!=null ? support[i].sdateTime : '';
    var type = support[i].type!=null ? support[i].type : '';
    var subtype = support[i].subtype!=null ? support[i].subtype : '';
    var status = support[i].status!=null ? support[i].status : '';
    var feedback = support[i].feedback!=null ? support[i].feedback : '';
    ticket = '<tr class="ticketRow" id="ticket'+i+'"><td>'+sdateTime+'</td>';
    ticket += '<td>'+type+'</td><td>'+subtype+'</td><td>'+status+'</td>   <td>'+feedback+'</td></tr>';
    container.append(ticket);
}
</script>
```

I built the table dynamically based on the length of a JSON object "support."
Now I want to change the text of subtype in the third row of the table. How can I do that with jquery? I'm trying with:

```
$('table support-table').children('tbody').children('tr').eq(3).eq(4).html("POSITIVE");
```

but I've been unsuccessful. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Now I want to change the text of sub-type in the third row` :- third row which td?

Comment: td that contains "subtype"

Comment: indexing is zero based and you are not looking for a `td`

Comment: "Dinamically I build the table based on the leght of a JSON object "support"" - so, when you do that, add a class to the td tag so you can reference ithe column when you need to easily

Comment: thank you guys, I solved the problem with $('td').eq(4).html("POSITIVE");